# Filling between multivalued curve and normal curve

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, filling

I have a multivalued curve p1 (left curve) and a normal curve xpr2 (right), and I want to fill the middle region between them as blue, and the rightmost region as red.

However, I get this extra filled part above my multivalued function, presumably because the xpr2 curve is above that part. Is there a way to get the plot to ignore filling beyond a certain point?

```
xpr1[y_] := 5.077959119860908` - 15.96152127464673` y^(1/3) + 11.632042032912723` Sqrt[y];
xpr2[x_] := 2.4673477623994344` - 1.8055789567179195` x + 0.5471986643936791` x^2 - 0.055509819604498495` x^3;
p1[y_] := {xpr1[y], y};
Plot[{xpr2[x], p1[y][[2]] /. NSolve[p1[y][[1]] == x]}, {x, 0, 2},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0.2, 1.2}}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, Blue}}}]
```

Result:

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Your function curves back on itself and filling in `Plot` is filling until it reaches the second plot. The filling meets the second plot outside of the plot range. You may have to use `ParametricPlot` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw branches separately and choose the right filling

```
p1[y_] := {xpr1[y], y};
Plot[{p1[y][[2]] /. NSolve[p1[y][[1]] == x][[1]], 
  p1[y][[2]] /. NSolve[p1[y][[1]] == x][[2]], xpr2[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All,
  Filling -> {3 -> {{1}, {Red, None}}, 1 -> {{2}, Blue}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is quite strange to see the filling artifacts (white pixels) under the top (blue) curve on your plot. I don't get these with version 10.3 on Win7 x64. What is you OS/version?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov version 10.3 on Linux

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[{
  RegionPlot[ y < xpr2[x] && x > xpr1[y] , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue],
  RegionPlot[ y > xpr2[x] && x > xpr1[y] , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red],
  Plot[xpr2[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Green],
  ParametricPlot[{xpr1[y], y}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Black]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't clip the plot with `PlotRange`, you will see that the filling is exactly as you asked for it to be.

```
Plot[{xpr2[x], p1[y][[2]] /. NSolve[p1[y][[1]] == x]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, Blue}}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: +1 Because I understood the same thing from the original post